# Find in Mountain Array problem leetcode 1095 using binary search algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, binary-search

Am trying to find the indices of the target number in an mountain array as mentioned in the leetcode [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-in-mountain-array/description/),but the descending array always gives -1 index of the target even when the target exists in the descending part. The ascending part does find the index correctly though.

The approach I used is to find the peak index of the mountain array and then do two binary searches from "o to peak index" in the first search and from "peak to end index" for the second search. Now the condition that I have applied is according to the version of answer am getting,i.e, am getting the first index of ans[] array correctly but the second index i.e, ans[1] is wrong .So to just keep the first index as the answer I applied this if else condition:

```
   if(ans[0]==-1 || ans[1]==-1){
            if(ans[0]>ans[1]){
                return ans[0];
            }else{
                return ans[1];
            }
        }else{
            return ans[0];
        }
```

but this condition fails when the ascending part doesn't have target and descending part has one, so the answer array is{-1,-1}. But I am not getting the reason why the descending part binary search is failing and the code doesn't give the correct answer. If only the first and second index comes right I can apply the correct if else condition. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong over here?

The whole answer code is as follows :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] nums = {1,5,2};
    int target=2;
    int answer=smallestIndex(nums,target);
    System.out.println(answer);
    }
    static int smallestIndex(int[]nums,int target){
        int peak = search(nums);
        int[] ans={-1,-1};
        int lastindex=nums.length-1;
        ans[0]= searchRange(nums,0,peak,target);
        ans[1]= searchRange(nums,peak,lastindex,target);
        if(ans[0]==-1 || ans[1]==-1){
            if(ans[0]>ans[1]){
                return ans[0];
            }else{
                return ans[1];
            }
        }else{
            return ans[0];
        }
    }
    static int search(int[] nums){
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
         while(start<end){
            int mid = start+(end-start)/2;
            if(nums[mid]>nums[mid+1]){
                end=mid;
            }else{
                start=mid+1;
            }
         }
         return start;
    }
    static int searchRange(int[] nums,int start,int end,int target){
        boolean isAsc;
        if(start<end){
            isAsc=true;
        }else{
            isAsc=false;
        }
    while(start<=end){
        int mid=start+(end-start)/2;
        if(isAsc){
            if(target==nums[mid]){
                return mid;
            }
                 if(target>nums[mid]){
            start=mid+1;
        }else{
            end=mid-1;
        }
        }else{
              if(target==nums[mid]){
                return mid;
            }
        if(target>nums[mid]){
            end=mid-1;
        }else{
            start=mid+1;
        }
        }
  
      
    }
      return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: since start and end comes closer to each other untill it gives the middle element i.e.' the target hence it would always return when target==middle.